# Jquery move div from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

im new here and Im not really experienced in webdesign, but i tried to make my own Website. I found this great Slider Menu from this page:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/28/awesome-cufonized-fly-out-menu/

The only problem is with my knowledge about jQuery i have no idea how to make the menu slide from right side to the left side and not - like now - from left to right.

I tried many things ive seen in this forum, but none of them worked.

This is the code of my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            Cufon.replace('a, span').CSS.ready(function() {
                var $menu       = $("#slidingMenu");

                /**
                * the first item in the menu, 
                * which is selected by default
                */
                var $selected   = $menu.find('li:first');

                /**
                * this is the absolute element,
                * that is going to move across the menu items
                * it has the width of the selected item
                * and the top is the distance from the item to the top
                */
                var $moving     = $('<li />',{
                    className   : 'move',
                    top         : $selected[0].offsetTop + 'px',
                    width       : $selected[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
                });

                /**
                * each sliding div (descriptions) will have the same top
                * as the corresponding item in the menu
                */
                $('#slidingMenuDesc > div').each(function(i){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.css('top',$menu.find('li:nth-child('+parseInt(i+2)+')')[0].offsetTop + 'px');
                });

                /**
                * append the absolute div to the menu;
                * when we mouse out from the menu 
                * the absolute div moves to the top (like innitially);
                * when hovering the items of the menu, we move it to its position 
                */
                $menu.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                        moveTo($selected,400);
                      })
                     .append($moving)
                     .find('li')
                     .not('.move')
                     .bind('mouseenter',function(){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var offsetLeft = $this.offset().left -20;
                        //slide in the description
                        $('#slidingMenuDesc > div:nth-child('+ parseInt($this.index()) +')').stop(true).animate({'width':offsetLeft+'px'},400, 'easeOutExpo');
                        //move the absolute div to this item
                        moveTo($this,400);
                      })
                      .bind('mouseleave',function(){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var offsetLeft = $this.offset().left -20;
                        //slide out the description
                        $('#slidingMenuDesc > div:nth-child('+ parseInt($this.index()) +')').stop(true).animate({'width':'0px'},400, 'easeOutExpo');
                      });;

                /**
                * moves the absolute div, 
                * with a certain speed, 
                * to the position of $elem
                */
                function moveTo($elem,speed){
                    $moving.stop(true).animate({
                        top     : $elem[0].offsetTop + 'px',
                        width   : $elem[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
                    }, speed, 'easeOutQuint');
                }
            }) ;
        });
    </script>
```

and thats the code from my style.css:

```
.slidingMenu {
position: absolute;
height:410px;
width: 410px;
top:200px;
overflow:hidden;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.slidingMenu li {
display:block;
float:right;
clear:both;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;}
.slidingMenu li.move {
width: 9px;
height: 68px;
right:0px;
padding-right:10px;
margin-top:2px;
z-index: 8;
position: absolute;    
background: #2183c4;     
background: 
    -webkit-gradient(
        linear, 
        left top, 
        left bottom, 
        from(#0771b8), 
        to(#2183c4)
    );     
background: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(
        top, 
        #0771b8, 
        #2183c4
    );     
-moz-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;  
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;        
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; 
border-top-left-radius: 8px;  
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;        
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;    }
 .slidingMenu li a {
font-size:66px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ddd;
outline: none;
text-indent:5px;
z-index: 10;
display: block;
float: right;
height: 66px;
line-height: 66px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding-right:10px;}

   .slidingMenuDesc{
margin-top:200px;
position:relative;}

    .slidingMenuDesc div{
background: #2183c4;     
background: 
    -webkit-gradient(
        linear, 
        left top, 
        left bottom, 
        from(#0771b8), 
        to(#2183c4)
    );     
background: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(
        top, 
        #0771b8, 
        #2183c4
    );      
height: 68px;
padding-right:5px;
left:-5px;
width:0px;
margin-top:2px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;  
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;       
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; 
border-top-right-radius: 8px;  
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; }
    .slidingMenuDesc div span {
font-size:36px;
color: #f0f0f0;
text-indent:5px;
z-index: 10;
display: block;
height: 66px;
line-height: 66px;
position:absolute;
right:10px;
margin-left:5px;
top:-3px;}
```

With taking the right:0px; in SliderMenu i got the Menu in the center of the page, but the slides still are coming from the left side.

It would be amazing if you can give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Took me forever to get it to work, here this what your html page should be.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Awesome Cufonized Fly Out Menu with jQuery and CSS3</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Awesome Cufonized Fly Out Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="cufon, jquery, css3, menu, navigation, slide out, fly out, hover"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="BabelSans_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                Cufon.replace('a, span').CSS.ready(function() {
                    var $menu       = $("#slidingMenu");

                    /**
                    * the first item in the menu, 
                    * which is selected by default
                    */
                    var $selected   = $menu.find('li:first');

                    /**
                    * this is the absolute element,
                    * that is going to move across the menu items
                    * it has the width of the selected item
                    * and the top is the distance from the item to the top
                    */
                    var $moving     = $('<li />',{
                        className   : 'move',
                        top         : $selected[0].offsetTop + 'px',
                        width       : $selected[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
                    });

                    /**
                    * each sliding div (descriptions) will have the same top
                    * as the corresponding item in the menu
                    */
                    $('#slidingMenuDesc > div').each(function(i){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.css('top',$menu.find('li:nth-child('+parseInt(i+2)+')')[0].offsetTop + 'px');
                    });

                    /**
                    * append the absolute div to the menu;
                    * when we mouse out from the menu 
                    * the absolute div moves to the top (like innitially);
                    * when hovering the items of the menu, we move it to its position 
                    */
                    $menu.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                            moveTo($selected,400);
                          })
                         .append($moving)
                         .find('li')
                         .not('.move')
                         .bind('mouseenter',function(){
                            var $this = $(this);
                            var offsetLeft = $this.offset().left - 20;
                            //slide in the description
                            $('#slidingMenuDesc > div:nth-child('+ parseInt($this.index()) +')').stop(true).animate({'width':offsetLeft+'px'},400, 'easeOutExpo');
                            //move the absolute div to this item
                            moveTo($this,400);
                          })
                          .bind('mouseleave',function(){
                            var $this = $(this);
                            var offsetLeft = $this.offset().left - 20;
                            //slide out the description
                            $('#slidingMenuDesc > div:nth-child('+ parseInt($this.index()) +')').stop(true).animate({'width':'0px'},400, 'easeOutExpo');
                          });;

                    /**
                    * moves the absolute div, 
                    * with a certain speed, 
                    * to the position of $elem
                    */
                    function moveTo($elem,speed){
                        $moving.stop(true).animate({
                            top     : $elem[0].offsetTop + 'px',
                            width   : $elem[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
                        }, speed, 'easeOutExpo');
                    }
                }) ;
            });
        </script>
        <style>
          span.reference{
              position:fixed;
              left:10px;
              bottom:10px;
              font-size:14px;
          }
          span.reference a{
              color:#aaa;
              text-decoration:none;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <span class="reference">
                <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/28/awesome-cufonized-fly-out-menu/">back to hello</a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="slidingMenuDesc" class="slidingMenuDesc">
           <div><span>hello1</span></div>
            <div><span>hello2</span></div>
            <div><span>hello</span></div>

        </div>



    <ul id="slidingMenu" class="slidingMenu"> 
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li> </ul>
        </ul>


    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:You forgot to source your script**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the -20 is because of the slide not to reach the menu point. Your answer doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: /edit: offset().right doesnt exist unfortunately..
you can get the right offset from this:
var offset = $this.offset();

       offset.right = $(window).width() - (offset.left + $this.outerWidth(true));

BUT: 
It still goes from the left side... No idea why

Comment: could you make a fiddle to describe your problem... Sorry for the mistakes, but I am a very visual person so I don't quite understand the problem

Comment: no idea how to use fiddles to create a jquery thing.
look here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/
this is the exmaple i use. i Want the bars come out from the right side and not from the left side. You understand :)?

Comment: can I see your entire html script, I could make one for you. It is kind of hard to make a fiddle with only Jquery/Js and CSS

Comment: Sure. 
its this:

<body>
        <div>
            <span class="reference">
                <a href="#">back to Hello</a>
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
  <h1>Welcome to: <i>Hello</i></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="slidingMenuDesc" class="slidingMenuDesc">
   <div><span>Hello 1</span></div>
   <div><span>Hello 2</span></div>
   <div><span>Hello</span></div>
  </div>
  <ul id="slidingMenu" class="slidingMenu">
   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </body>

Comment: looks like a div issue, if you are trying to get it to slide out... Fixing it and making fiddle, may take a while

Comment: oh damn.. i think your got me wrong :D 
the Html page of mine is working, but i want to let the 
<div id="slidingMenuDesc" class="slidingMenuDesc">
           <div><span>hello1</span></div>
            <div><span>hello2</span></div>
            <div><span>hello</span></div>

        </div>

slide in from RIGHT to LEFT and NOT from left to right...